# Visual Studio C# Updating Localized Languages resx

Tags: c#, localization, multilingual, resx

I have multi Language Application, first it was made in English only,
than one time i added support for German and Russian version and send resx files for translation to mates.
But while they do translation, i added few more checkboxes in GUI
and now when i copy their files and load German \ Russian GUI version those not translated checkboxes do not shown in in those languages.

My Question is:
Is there a way to update localized .resx files to version of main, as i can see it:
in Localized files if controls are missing - they will display in default language.

For translation they used: Zeta Resource Editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer by myself :) Maybe someone need it:

In this free program (Zeta Resource Editor) You can Add group of existing resources from Your VS Project - just select them an add, Zeta Resource Editor will auto show which strings are missing, so you can easily find them.